# need libmysqlclient.so.14

Tags: mysql, rpm, rhel4

Where could I find a old RPM of MySQL client utilities. I am not sure which one, all I know is that Apache fails to load PHP with this message:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 3 of
>   /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
>   Cannot load
>   /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
>   into server: libmysqlclient.so.14:
>   cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Googling got me to here

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/12470926/dir/redhat_el_4/com/mysqlclient14-4.1.22-1.el4.remi.i386.rpm.html

which led me to the RPM here

ftp://mirror.switch.ch/pool/1/mirror/mysql/Downloads/MySQL-4.1/MySQL-shared-standard-4.1.22-0.rhel4.i386.rpm

This worked for me since I needed it as soon as possible, but I wouldn't call this route best practice. It did get my site back up though.

Answer (score 0):

what version of redhat are you running ? you can find the rpms on ftp.redhat.com

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql` package that comes with EL4 contains libmysqlclient.so.14. If you've installed a newer version from another source then you'll need to rebuild PHP for it.